# Holomorphic function has infinite many derivatives (proof without using Cauchy theorem)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be an holomorphic function. It is possible to prove that it has infinitely many derivatives but without using Cauchy theorem?

It is not an homework from my math class, it is just a curiosity.
Hope someone could help or give a reference.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by holomorphic? Complex differentiable on a domain? If so, infinite differentiability follows from the theory of elliptic operators but is considerably more complicated than using Cauchy

Comment: If you want to prove $f$ is differentiable in a domain $\implies f$ is analytic, there's an integration free approach in Whyburn's *Topological Analysis*-- a rough walk-through of this is also given in the Appendix to Beardon's *Complex Analysis*